# Bootstrap tab doesn't switch

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I'm making a little page containing bootstrap tabs to switch between chat windows.
I think I've correctly followed the example, but this won't work:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="navbartabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#placeholder">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#chat-patient+email.com">Patient, Peter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabcontent">
        <div id="placeholder" class="tab-pane active">
            Placeholder
        </div>
        <div id="chat-patient+email.com" class="tab-pane">
            <ul id="content-patient+email.com"></ul>
            <input id="input-patient+email.com"><button id="send-patient+email.com">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can use the nav tab buttons and they do get the visual effect, byt the tab contents don't switch around the `active` class.

If I edit the source on the webpage, I can make the second tab show up by adding the `active` class and removing it from the placeholder tab.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/57159/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `id` that contains "." or "+" causes a problem with the jQuery selector. You need to escape the tab selector like this...

`data-target="#chat-patient\+email\.com"`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="navbartabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#placeholder">Placeholder</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href data-target="#chat-patient\+email\.com">Patient, Peter</a></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5aqtqLv0/

Or, just remove the + and . from the `id`.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="navbartabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#placeholder">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#chat-patient">Patient, Peter</a></li>
    </ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yun3Lzsk/

Comment: You're welcome, and I added another option if you must leave the special chars in the id.